# Work permit doesn't have full name

Tags: working-visas, estonia

My middle name is not included in the Estonian short term employment registration, referred to as STER (work permit).

It has both my surname and the first name, but not the middle name. The employer confirmed that the entire name had been submitted during the registration process.

I'd like to know if this will be an issue during the visa application procedure?

*We assume the middle name was omitted due to it's length, however it may be confirmed in the database using the ID number.*